# C++ OO design: Inheritance of template parameter

Tags: c++, oop, templates, inheritance

I have an inheritance chain with Base being the base class. I want to be able to write a class template which inherits Base and possible another Base-derived class. I could use virtual inheritance, but I found another solution. I'd like to know if it's common/considerable/legitimate class design:

Write a class template in which the template parameter is the class it derives from, i.e. it has to be Base or a Base-derived class. In the constructor I can use static assert to really make sure the user didn't use any illegal class as the template parameter.

If it works, I won't ever have virtual inheritance problems... the question is, it it ok to do that. I never saw it in other projects, so I want to make sure before I use it.

**EDIT**: Just to be sure I don't confuse you, here's some code:

```
class Base
{
};

class Derived : public Base
{
};

template <Class TheBase>
class MyDerived : public TheBase
{
};
```

Now I can use `Base` or any `Base`-derived class, e.g. `Derived`, as the `TheBase` parameter.

Comment: Could you show us some code? I think it would help to get better answers.

Comment: Honestly it sounds like you'r describing the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: "I won't ever have virtual inheritance problems"... Have you ever heard of Murphy's law? :)

Comment: It is not clear at all what problem you are trying to solve. Can you show code that would be replaced with this solution?

Answer (score 23):

This is a valid design pattern. It is mixin inheritance, not CRTP. Mixin inheritance provides a way to simulate multiple inheritance safely by the programmer manually linearizing the inheritance hierarchy. The templated classes are the mixins. If you want to extend a class with multiple mixins you have to decide the order of the composition like `Big<Friendly<Dog> >`.
Mixin programming in C++ is described in this [Dr Dobb's article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/mixin-based-programming-in-c/184404445).
Mixins can be used to implement a static version the GoF Decorator pattern as described [here](http://www.reenigne.org/blog/mixins-in-cpp/).
Mixins play a simlar role in C++ that traits (not C++ traits) play in Scala & SmallTalk.

In [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern#General_form) it is the base class that is a template:

```
template <class Param>
class Base { ... };

class Derived : public Base<Derived> { ... };
```

Comment: Indeed not CRTP. Thanks for pointing it out, Daniel Mahler. I have revised my own answer, I'm not a big fan of misleading people.

Answer (score 10):

Later edit: One year later, here I am revising my own answer. I initially erroneously stated that the pattern OP posted was CRTP. This is not correct. It is indeed a mixin, please read Daniel Mahler's answer lower on the page for the correct explanation.

Original: It is ok to use such a design. [WTL](http://wtl.sourceforge.net/) uses it for example. It is used to implement [Static Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming#Static_polymorphism) and is called [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: Not exactly CRTP, but still useful. It's good for selecting replaceable interfaces, for example.

Answer (score 8):

This is fine, as Zadirion points out.  The reason it works (simplified) is that templates in C++, unlike generics in C#, are compile-time.  It would be remiss of me to say "it's a typedef" and I'd get a lot of flak for it, but let's keep it simple and say it was.

Consider:

```
class base {
protected:
    base() { };
    virtual ~base() { };
};

template<class T>
class super : public T {
};
```

and later:

```
super<base> s;
```

Absolutely fine.  This is actually a rather beautiful construct.  Because it is compile time, you can *choose your base class*, which in some design idioms could be very favourable.

Comment: +1 for going into a bit more detail than me. I would add that this is quite a useful pattern when you need to write some reusable code as a base class people would derive from, but some of the code wouldn't be able to operate with derived classes of certain types. In that case, the pattern could be used in the base class to determine what properties the derived type has (such as std::is_base_of) and enable certain code when certain conditions are met.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I added some code in the post to make sure my description doesn't confuse people

Answer (score 5):

Here is a good motto: **Use templating for the types, but inheritance for behavior.**

Stick to it. There are certainly a lot of short cuts / tricks that you might use to get the work done, but in the long run these bad design choices will be headaches. If you want to use such, make sure to research the benefits and drawbacks.

Now, going back to your question, what you asked is possible to do: see [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), and [Static polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming#Static_polymorphism).

Comment: -1. By that motto we would have no policy-based design. Not such a good point after all.

Comment: It is not saying 'do not ever use such design', it is to encourage people to re-think their choices. This has noting to do with well established design paradigms like the Policy design. You are totally missing the point.

Comment: I undid my downvote. Nonetheless, the motto you are quoting is formulated as a rule, which I don't necessarily find correct.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are talking about the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), which is valid C++.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is to inherit from two classes which may have a common base class, is that correct? In that case you shoul deal with virtual inheritance problems (i.e. you'll have to declare as *virtual* the inheritance of the base class for both the two classes you're interested in). That would just cause a small (likely insignificant) overhead due to some runtime support (2 vpointers more).

Your code isn't the CRTP (in CRTP the base class is the one templated receiving the derived class) and doesn't seem to address in any way the double inheritance problem you was trying to get rid of.

As far as I can see it you can either accept virtual inheritance and use the *virtual* keyword incurring in a minimal overhead or you can refactor your code.

I didn't completely understand what you're trying to do but if you're trying to inherit from two different classes with a common base class (virtual inheritance is all about this) and for some reason you don't want to use the *virtual* keyword, then you might use the CRTP in the following fashion:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class Derived>
class Base
{
public:
    void basefunc() { cout << "base here"<< endl; }
    virtual void polyfunc() { cout << "base poly here"<< endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
public:
    void derivedfunc() { cout << "derived here"<< endl; }
    virtual void polyfunc() { cout << "derived poly here"<< endl; }
};

class OtherDerived : public Base<OtherDerived>
{
public:
    void otherderivedfunc() { cout << "otherderived here"<< endl; }
    virtual void polyfunc() { cout << "otherderived poly here"<< endl; }
};

class InheritingFromBoth : public Derived, public OtherDerived
{
public:
    void inheritingfunc() { cout << "inheritingfromboth here" << endl; }
    virtual void polyfunc() { cout << "inheritingfromboth poly here"<< endl; }  
};

int main() {

    Derived obj;
    OtherDerived obj2;

    InheritingFromBoth *obj3 = new InheritingFromBoth();
    Derived *der = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(obj3);
    der->polyfunc();
    OtherDerived *der2 = dynamic_cast<OtherDerived*>(obj3);
    der2->polyfunc();

    Base<Derived>* bptr = dynamic_cast<Base<Derived>*>(obj3);
    bptr->polyfunc();
    Base<OtherDerived>* bptr2 = dynamic_cast<Base<OtherDerived>*>(obj3);
    bptr2->polyfunc();



    return 0;
}
```

by creating two different instances of the base class you'll avoid inheritance ambiguities.

A simpler, perhaps cleaner, better solution if you intend to inherit from a base and a base-derived class at the same time is the following:

- Inheriting from a class Base **and** from a Base-derived class makes me think that you want to be able to access Base methods and Base-derived methods at the same time..

if you pay attention in your class designing to potential *name-hiding* [problems](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/c-name-hiding/) and just use polymorphism to "customize" the behavior of functions you actually want to be different (and that can be cast-controlled), then a clean hierarchy as `Base -> Derived -> YourClass` could eventually solve your problems.

In your specific case your approach works, as noted by others as been used throughout many applications but I don't think can effectively solve your double inheritance issue. Eventually only the specific design case can lead to the *lesser-evil* solution.